# File not uploading when validation with form requests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

### Description

Hi guys,
I have a API endpoint, and im validation incoming data with form requests,
It validated correctly but when i requesting file it says file doesn't exists.

### Code

`controller method`

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    $owner = $request->user();
    $garage = $owner->garages()->findOrFail($request->garage_id);
    $certificate = $garage->certificates()->create($request->validated());
    $certificate->addMedia($request->file('image'))->toMediaCollection('certificateImage');
    return $this->noContent();
}
```

`FormRequest`

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|filled',
        'garage_id' => ['bail', 'required', 'exists:multi-vendor.garages,id', new GarageIsOwn],
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,bmp'
    ];
}
```

### Error

```
{
    "message": "خطای سرور",
    "errors": [
        "The file \"C:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpAB2C.tmp\" does not exist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe you should check permissions, and remember files will be deleted from `tmp` directory after the request is completed. it means files only are accessible within the request and you can't access them after the request is completed.

Comment: you should add this attribute in your form tag. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @AmirKhaledian it's API request.

Comment: @MohammadSalehi i think it's Symfony's bug.